# How to Add Sheet Page and Template to Altium Pcb Doc?

Tags: altium

I want to add a page in pcb file like here and I want to assign a template. I will add manufacturers notes etc. to the side. I changed the sheet setting lengths from the properties section, but there was no change. Does anyone know?
[image]

[image]

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-mechanical-layers
[image]

system colors make visible the sheet

Comment: This link will take you, with a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: [https://forum.live.altium.com/](https://forum.live.altium.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember right, to get this view, you need to add the page layer to your altium template.

Honestly, I did that in the past and went back on it. The main issue is that it is hard to center the PCB on the sheet. (unless there's a way to do it). I thought it would make more professional PCB design, but it only lasted one or 2 design before I threw all that away. I think you should look into Draftsman instead. This is way more efficient way to do prints of PCB design that will scale much better!

Edit: Let me offer a way to do it that will work, be simple and efficient. Instead of using the legacy tools in AD, what I would do is create a component that would be mechanical with all the outline and title block in a mechanical layer. Then, I would add this component to create the sheet instead of doing a PCB template. That would give you all the same benefits as using a template without all it's limitations.

Comment: I do all this in Draftsman which allows various types of documentation for pcb manufacture, assembly, and making flip-books of the layers.

Comment: yes, I use draftsman too. 2 company I worked before always sent such pcb files and I wondered how to open and close them. Draftsman is really perfect.